# Reset a crypted password

Tags: passwords, password-encryption, pagekit

Does anyone know how PageKit CMS stores the admin password? I've installed it, created the account and then the password is wrong. In the database the password is hashed so I have to decrypt it or create another one using the same cryptography method.

NB: The reset password link is useless as I don't have mailing on this server.

The password is:

> $2y$10$74yJFPijNzIA0ZJY4Ggy5eCRzRMhaCuj2Xw2S8fvd1yE9zZrxRU0y

and it's supposed to be "testtest".

Comment: Well, it's not 'testtest', but you could use an online tool to generate a new hash for whatever password you want, and replace the value directly to the database.

Comment: Yes! That's what I mean, because I have to know the the hashing type to generate a new one with the same hash and replace the existing one.

Answer (score 1):

The "password" looks like `bcrypt` format and that is a hash not encryption. The difference is that a hash is one-way, that is non reversible. The only choices are to run a password cracking program but the chances of success are really bad, update the password hash if possible or re-install.